# WordPress API & Polylang: How to get categoires for specific country/language?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, polylang

**My goal**

I want to be able to send a request like this `https://myblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?language=4` to get only the categories that are assigned to my language with the ID 4.

**What I have tried**
I have already added the code mentioned by `@mastababa` [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-know-the-language-of-a-post-through-the-wordpress-rest-api/).
So now I am able to call `https://myblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/language` to get all languages defined by me via the plugin [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) and after that I can call `https://myblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?language=4` to get all posts only for the language with the ID 4.

I am using Wordpress 5.5.1 and Polylang 2.8.3

Thanks for your help!

Comment: look at this topic - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-know-the-language-of-a-post-through-the-wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: @AngelDeykov I have already mentioned this link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by default you need **Polylang Pro** to be able to do that. See docs: https://polylang.pro/doc/rest-api/ Then you can call API like this: `https://myblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?lang=en`